# Admin panel problem 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-panel

I have problem with so old version Magento (customer didn't moved for a whole time). I can login in admin panel, but nothing can press. No one button, any action, nothing.

I tried this one:
increased

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

and clear cache

```
 sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

But nothing happens(

Answer (score 0):

To debug this,

**Initial Steps to identify the issue**

- check the browser console to get any errors reported
- check the system.log and exception.log in var/log directories
- check the PHP and Webserver (Apache / Ngingx) logs

If its a production store, enable the maintenance mode (add the maintenance.flag) and enable the developer mode in index.php file

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); // Enables Developer Mode
```

You can also keep the store in production mode and enable the developer mode only for your IP in index.php

```
$allowed = array('xx.xxx.xx.xxx);
if (in_array($ip, $allowed)) { 
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); // Enables Developer Mode
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); // lets also set this, though turning on developer mode is sufficient
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE); 
}
```

These steps are very much sufficient to get the actual error behind the issue that you face.

> *As a sidenote, Have been working with Magento since 1.3.x. days and*
> **these steps are so basic and fundamental to solve the page loading**
> **issues due to non-explicit fatal errors / exceptions, that every backend magento developer should know.**